# Does modifying metric of a space change the limit of a sequence in it?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Im reading Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis and get this idea. In my opinion, doing it will remove or add some limit points in the space because this modification may change the radius of their neighborhood.

Im not sure whether it will exert effects on a limit of a convergent sequence. For example, {(1+1/n)|n∈$N$} in $R$ usual does converge to 1 and will it still converge to 1 when its metric is modified by d(x,y)=|1/x-1/y|? Or another question that we know (0,1) is open in $R$ usual, can you turn it to a closed set in $R$ just by modifying its metric?

Comment: You might want to another metric as this one looks a bit undefined at 0. In general, the limits can change if you change the metric. I'm not sure about the second question, but probably yes

Comment: @Horstenson, sorry I made a mistake. The convergent point should be 1 and 0 is actually undefined as you said.

Comment: For the second question, it suffices to take the discrete metric.

Comment: @JPLF: Ohhhh, awesomeeee!Make sense

Comment: @Frank_W Ok, I probably could have guessed, that $1+1/n$ converges to 1. In the changed metric this becomes $d(1+1/n,1)=|1/(1+1/n) - 1|=|(1/n)/(1+1/n)|=|1/(1+n)|$ and this should converge to zero as well.

Comment: @Horstenson: Yes. {(1+1/n)|n∈$N$} will still converge to 1 under the Metric d(x,y)=|1/x-1/y|, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following metric: \[d(x,y) = |f(x) - f(y)|\]
where $f$ is the function that swaps the real numbers $7$ and $903$ and leaves every other real number untouched.

With this metric, the sequence $x_n = 7 + 1/n$ converges to $903$, so yes, different metrics can have completely different limits of sequences.